# Stacked Bar Chart in Matplotlib; Series Are Overlaying Instead Of Stacking

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Struggling to figure this one out. I have a stacked bar chart that I'm trying to create with Python / Matplotlib and it seems to be overlaying the data instead of stacking resulting in different colors (i.e. red+yellow = orange instead of stacking red and yellow). Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Here's my code:

```
#Stacked Bar Char- matplotlib

#Create the general blog and the "subplots" i.e. the bars
f, ax1 = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(10,5))
# Set the bar width
bar_width = 0.75
# positions of the left bar-boundaries
bar_l = [i+1 for i in range(len(df4['bikes']))] 
# positions of the x-axis ticks (center of the bars as bar labels)
tick_pos = [i+(bar_width/2) for i in bar_l] 

# Create a bar plot, in position bar_1
ax1.bar(bar_l, df4['bikes1'], width=bar_width, label='bikes', alpha=0.5,color='r', align='center')
# Create a bar plot, in position bar_1
ax1.bar(bar_l, df4['bikes'], width=bar_width,alpha=0.5,color='r', align='center')
# Create a bar plot, in position bar_1
ax1.bar(bar_l, df4['cats1'], width=bar_width, label='cats', alpha=0.5,color='y', align='center')
# Create a bar plot, in position bar_1
ax1.bar(bar_l, df4['cats'], width=bar_width,alpha=0.5,color='y', align='center')

# set the x ticks with names
plt.xticks(tick_pos, df4['Year'])
# Set the label and legends
ax1.set_ylabel("Count")
ax1.set_xlabel("Year")
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
ax1.axhline(y=0, color='k')
ax1.axvline(x=0, color='k')


# Set a buffer around the edge
plt.xlim([min(tick_pos)-bar_width, max(tick_pos)+bar_width])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to manually calculate position from which your *cats* bar will start (look at the `bottom` variable in my code when *cats* are plotting).  You have to propose your own method to calculate position of *cats* bars depending on data in your dataframe.

Your colors are mixed up because you use `alpha` variable and when bars overlayed then colors would mixed up:

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df4 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'bikes1':[-1,-2,-3,-4,-5,-3], 'bikes':[10,20,30,15,11,11],
 'cats':[1,2,3,4,5,6], 'cats1':[-6,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1], 'Year': [2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017]})


#Create the general blog and the "subplots" i.e. the bars
f, ax1 = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(10,5))
# Set the bar width
bar_width = 0.75
# positions of the left bar-boundaries
bar_l = [i+1 for i in range(len(df4['bikes']))] 
# positions of the x-axis ticks (center of the bars as bar labels)
tick_pos = [i+(bar_width/2) for i in bar_l] 

# Create a bar plot, in position bar_1
ax1.bar(bar_l, df4['bikes1'], width=bar_width, label='bikes', alpha=0.5,color='r', align='center')
# Create a bar plot, in position bar_1
ax1.bar(bar_l, df4['bikes'], width=bar_width,alpha=0.5,color='r', align='center')
# Create a bar plot, in position bar_1
ax1.bar(bar_l, df4['cats1'], width=bar_width, label='cats', alpha=0.5,color='y', align='center',
 bottom=[min(i,j) for i,j in zip(df4['bikes'],df4['bikes1'])])
# Create a bar plot, in position bar_1
ax1.bar(bar_l, df4['cats'], width=bar_width,alpha=0.5,color='y', align='center',
 bottom=[max(i,j) for i,j in zip(df4['bikes'],df4['bikes1'])])


# set the x ticks with names
plt.xticks(tick_pos, df4['Year'])
# Set the label and legends
ax1.set_ylabel("Count")
ax1.set_xlabel("Year")
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
ax1.axhline(y=0, color='k')
ax1.axvline(x=0, color='k')

# Set a buffer around the edge
plt.xlim([min(tick_pos)-bar_width, max(tick_pos)+bar_width])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a bunch for your help!